# C function to Python (different results)

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, lfsr

I am trying to port this snippet of code to python from C. The outputs are different even though it's the same code.

This is the C version of the code which works:

```
int main(void)
{

uint8_t pac[] = {0x033,0x55,0x22,0x65,0x76};
uint8_t len = 5;
uint8_t chan = 0x64;

btLeWhiten(pac, len, chan);

    for(int i = 0;i<=len;i++)
    {
        printf("Whiten %02d \r\n",pac[i]);
     }

   while(1)
   {    

   }

  return 0;
  }



void btLeWhiten(uint8_t* data, uint8_t len, uint8_t whitenCoeff)
{

uint8_t  m;

while(len--){   
    for(m = 1; m; m <<= 1){

        if(whitenCoeff & 0x80){

            whitenCoeff ^= 0x11;
            (*data) ^= m;
        }
        whitenCoeff <<= 1;

    }
    data++;
  }
}
```

What I currently have in Python is:

```
def whiten(data, len, whitenCoeff):
    idx = len 
    while(idx > 0):
        m = 0x01
        for i in range(0,8):
            if(whitenCoeff & 0x80):
                whitenCoeff ^= 0x11
                data[len - idx -1 ] ^= m
                whitenCoeff <<= 1 
                m  <<= 0x01

        idx = idx - 1


pac = [0x33,0x55,0x22,0x65,0x76]
len = 5
chan = 0x64

def main():

whiten(pac,5,chan)
print pac


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The problem i see is that whitenCoeff always remain 8 bits in the C snippet but it gets larger than 8 bits in Python on each loop pass.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that Python always uses bigger numeric types (`int` at least) so your Python code works with a different sized type (which would explain the different result)

Answer (score 1):

In C you are writing data from 0 to len-1 but in Python you are writing data from -1 to len-2. Remove the -1 from this line:

```
data[len - idx -1 ] ^= m
```

like this

```
data[len - idx] ^= m
```

you also need to put this line outside the if:

```
whitenCoeff <<= 1
```

Comment: vicious thing: you'd believe you'd be protected by array out of bounds but not in this case (good find, although it's not the question it could have been the next one :))

Comment: That's probably the reason why np arrays don't support negative indices

Answer (score 1):

`whitenCoeff <<= 1` in C becomes 0 after a while because it is a 8-bit data.

In python, there's no such limit, so you have to write:

```
whitenCoeff = (whitenCoeff<<1) & 0xFF
```

to mask higher bits out.

(don't forget to check vz0 remark on array boundary)

plus there was an indentation issue.

rewritten code which gives same result:

```
def whiten(data, whitenCoeff):
    idx = len(data)
    while(idx > 0):
        m = 0x01
        for i in range(0,8):
            if(whitenCoeff & 0x80):
                whitenCoeff ^= 0x11
                data[-idx] ^= m
            whitenCoeff = (whitenCoeff<<1) & 0xFF
            m  <<= 0x01

        idx = idx - 1


pac = [0x33,0x55,0x22,0x65,0x76]
chan = 0x64

def main():

    whiten(pac,chan)
    print(pac)


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Slightly off-topic: Note that the C version already has problems:

```
for(int i = 0;i<=len;i++)
```

should be

```
for(int i = 0;i<len;i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few more problems.

1. `whitenCoeff <<= 1;` is outside of the `if` block in your C code, but it's inside of the `if` block in your Python code.
2. `data[len - idx -1 ] ^= m` wasn't translated correctly, it works backwards from the C code.

This code produces the same output as your C code:

```
def whiten(data, whitenCoeff):
    for index in range(len(data)):
        for i in range(8):
            if (whitenCoeff & 0x80):
                whitenCoeff ^= 0x11
                data[index] ^= (1 << i)

            whitenCoeff = (whitenCoeff << 1) & 0xff

    return data

if __name__=="__main__":
    print whiten([0x33,0x55,0x22,0x65,0x76], 0x64)
```

Comment: idx is initialized to len, incremented by -1. idx takes 10,9,8, and (len-idx) takes 0,1,2,...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by anding the python code with 0xFF. That keeps the variable from increasing beyond 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in `C` does not appear to work as intended since it displays one more value than is available in `pac`. Correcting for this should cause 5 values to be displayed instead of 6 values. To copy the logic from `C` over to `Python`, the following was written in an attempt to duplicate the results:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
def main():
    pac = bytearray(b'\x33\x55\x22\x65\x76')
    chan = 0x64
    bt_le_whiten(pac, chan)
    print('\n'.join(map('Whiten {:02}'.format, pac)))


def bt_le_whiten(data, whiten_coeff):
    for offset in range(len(data)):
        m = 1
        while m & 0xFF:
            if whiten_coeff & 0x80:
                whiten_coeff ^= 0x11
                data[offset] ^= m
            whiten_coeff <<= 1
            whiten_coeff &= 0xFF
            m <<= 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To simulate 8-bit unsigned integers, the snippet `& 0xFF` is used in several places to truncate numbers to the proper size. The `bytearray` data type is used to store `pac` since that appears to be the most appropriate storage method in this case. The code still needs documentation to properly understand it.